# Cypress works on local machine but no in Gitlab CI

Tags: angular, gitlab, continuous-integration, cypress

I am using cypress to test my Angular-App. When I am running it local everything works fine. As soon as I am running it in Gitlab CI it fails.

package.json

```
"ci:start-server": "angular-http-server --path ./dist/angularWeb2 -p 4200",
"cy:run": "npx cypress run --headless --browser chrome",
"ci:cy-run": "start-server-and-test ci:start-server http://localhost:4200 cy:run"
```

Gitlab-ci.yml

```
image: image: cypress/browsers:node16.13.2-chrome97-ff96
script: npm run ci:cy-run
```

Answer (score -1):

On CI, your machine may not be equipped with all the dependencies it needs like your local. You'll have to install those and prior to running your Cypress tests.

You'll have to configure your `.yml` file in order to install the dependencies needed for Cypress and any others if you are building your app.

This is a good reference for [Cypress with Gitlab](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/continuous-integration/gitlab-ci#Basic-Setup).